# Where is Request.ClientCertificate in ASP.net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, certificate, x509

Currently I'm developing an application with ASP.net 5 and it needs to get client certificates. The certificate used to be in Request.ClientCertificate and was available in a controller (v. 4.6), but now there is no such option in Request.

I'm not bonded to Core, because the application is only for Windows and IIS => I've set in **project.json** just **.net 4.5.2** instead of *dnx451* and *dnxcore50* in the frameworks section, but the option hasn't appeared.

Is there any workaround or a particular library I should add to use client certificates in controllers with ASP.net 5 (RC1) or it is simply better to write the application on ASP.net 4.6?

Thank you in advance!